# using CMake to build Google Test

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am trying to use CMake to build Google Test.
As mentioned in the README of Google Test,
I have issued following commands:

```
  mkdir mybuild       # Create a directory to hold the build output.
  cd mybuild
  cmake D:\gtest-1.6.0 # (in the README this was set as:cmake ${GTEST_DIR}, but since on my machine D:\gtest-1.6.0 is where I have downloaded gtest, I have used that in command prompt.
```

And here is the error I get:
[image]

Any help? any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck with it and can't move forward...... Thanks.
ps. I have Visual Studio 10 installed on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Visual c++ compiler with cmake you must launch it from the Visual c++ command prompt. Otherwise cmake will not found your compiler.

Comment: Hi, yes I have Visual Studio 10 installed. And I downloaded CMake 2.6 too. ps. What is "dev command prompt"?

Comment: I edited my answer. You'll find it in the visual studio application folder. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for info

Comment: Hi, thanks but I get same issue even if I use Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010). : ((

Comment: Please post what D:\gtest-1.6.0\CMakeLists.txt contains.

Comment: Hi, please look here: http://www.filedropper.com/cmakelists - it was too big to copy and paste here..

Comment: Try deleting D:\MyBuild\CMakeCache.txt then running `cmake D:\gtest-1.6.0` from the Visual Studio command prompt.